# Failed to open excel(.xlsx) with NPOI(2.5.6) with too many graph

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Currently I'm trying to open the excel (workbook) which contain many sheets and each of the sheet contain multiple graphs. Unfortunately, I cannot open the file and it throws error, but the error is empty string "" which is weird.

So what I tried is deleting the graph one by one, and then I can open the file.

It seems only 1 graph that cause the error, is there any specific graph that NPOI can handle and cannot handle?

May I know what cause this kind of behavior?

[The graph that causes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Ah7.png)
[The given error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhD9U.jpg)

Comment: Post your code and the error as text in the question itself. NPOI is one of the many packages used to *create* Excel files. You don't need it to read data. What are you trying to do? If you want to read data, something like ExcelDataReader will be simpler and faster. It's another matter if you need to use an existing Excel file as a template.

Comment: Post the full exception text, not just the message. An exception contain any inner exceptions and a stack trace with that shows the function that failed *and* the function calls that led to it. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()` or `Console.WriteLine(exc);`. You can also copy it directly from the Exception popup while debugging by clicking on the `Copy Details` button

Comment: Have you tried any *other* Excel library like EPPlus or ClosedXML? NPOI is one of the oldest libraries but not the most popular or easier to use when it comes to Excel specifically.